# "Return;" a parent method in the stack-trace

Tags: ios, objective-c, linux, multithreading, methods

In objective-c (running linux), say I have a method-A which calls a method-B and inside method-B I call `return;`.

```
a {
    //stuff
    [self b];
    //stuff
}

b {
    //stuff
    return;
    //stuff
}
```

When I call `return` inside method-B, it will still finish the rest of method "A" (the parent method). But what if I need to return the method from which method B is being called as well (the parent-method, method-A).

Does Objective-C have a `superReturn;` or `returnAll;` type function? Right now I'm just setting BOOLs that I check after method-B is finished being called inside method-A.

I'm assuming there is some way to access the stack trace directly w/ **linux commands** and return-all. Maybe some **thread commands** exist too just for `return;`ing the current thread.

Comment: Well, I'm going to say "No, your can't." I'm also going to say "No, you shouldn't." Which implies... well, there *is* a way if you really, really want to... search for `using exceptions for flow control` and read about why that's a bad idea :)

Comment: I don't understand why using a `return;` is a good idea but preforming that same action to the parent method would be a bad idea. Also I'll look into that, thanks!

Comment: I agree with DonMag that it's usually a bad idea to do this kind of flow control (return from two methods.) If you cannot find another way to solve the problem, I suggest you expand on the details of why you want such a thing. What does method-A do? What does method-B do? What is the overall requirement you are trying to implement? Because the 'superReturn' thing looks a lot like an XY-problem.

Comment: It's a really bad idea for method B to dictate what should happen inside other methods that may call it. It would probably help if you updated your question with a more concrete example of what you are trying to accomplish. There is likely a proper solution but your question is far too focused on a specific solution instead of focusing on the more general issue. See [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @rmaddy I already have a practical solution for my one specific example, I just return a BOOL for if I want to return the second method or not. I was just wondering if such a super-return command existed or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Block Solution

Blocks may be a good approach to controlling this flow as desired with no negative impacts, given that no built in `superReturn;` exists.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [self methodA];
}

-(void)methodA {
    NSLog(@"1");
    NSLog(@"2");
    __block BOOL superReturn;
    [self methodB:^(NSNumber * _Nullable shouldSuperReturn) {
        if (shouldSuperReturn) {
            superReturn = [shouldSuperReturn boolValue];
        }
    }];
    if (superReturn) {
        return;
    }
    NSLog(@"3");
    NSLog(@"4");
}

-(void)methodB:(void(^)(NSNumber * _Nullable shouldSuperReturn))superReturn; {
    NSLog(@"a");
    NSLog(@"b");
    superReturn(@(YES));
    return;
    NSLog(@"c");
    NSLog(@"d");
}

//Logs 1,2,a,b.
```

Note: The Nullable flag w/ NSNumber type is optional. This can be accomplished with just BOOL given that failing to pass a value back through the block will result in a NO anyways.